# Update with row_number() not working, why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_overview
(
  obj_uid uuid,
  obj_parent_uid uuid,
  obj_no integer,
  obj_text text,
  obj_path text,
  isdir integer,
  intid bigint,
  intparentid bigint
)
```

I want to move from `uuid` to `bigint` and created the new columns `intid` and `intparentid`. I need a unique integer (`obj_uid` is the primary key) for `intid`, so I just wanted to update with `row_number() over (order by ...)`.

Did not seem to work. So I tried to write the results into a temp table, and update via join. But I got `1` for every `intid`.

But when I select from the join where I do the update, I get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc. What am I missing?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TEMP TABLE mytable AS
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT obj_uid, obj_parent_uid, obj_no
        , obj_text, obj_path, isdir
        , intid as cteIntId
        , intparentid as cteParentId
        , row_number() over (order by obj_uid) as rn 
    FROM T_Overview 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;

UPDATE T_Overview SET intid = mytable.rn 
FROM T_Overview AS bt 
INNER JOIN mytable 
    ON mytable.obj_uid = bt.obj_uid 


-- UPDATE T_Overview SET intid = CTE.rn FROM CTE;
-- UPDATE T_Overview SET intparentid = CTE.intid FROM CTE;
```

Comment: `obj_parent_uid` is a self-reference (referencing `t_overview` itself), right?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: Correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28804836/939860) already provided an explanation for your error.

But you don't need the temporary table at all:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK T_Overview;  -- if there is concurrent write access

WITH cte AS (
   SELECT obj_uid, obj_parent_uid
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY obj_uid) AS intid
   FROM   T_Overview 
   )
UPDATE  T_Overview t
SET     intid       = upd.intid 
      , intparentid = upd.intparentid
FROM   (
   SELECT t1.*, t2.intid AS intparentid
   FROM   cte t1
   LEFT   JOIN cte t2 ON t2.obj_uid = t1.obj_parent_uid
   ) upd
WHERE t.obj_uid = upd.obj_uid;

COMMIT;
```

The transaction wrapper and the explicit lock are only needed if there can be concurrent write access. (Even more so with a temp table, where you have a *much* bigger time slot in between.)

Assuming referential integrity - a FK constraint from `T_Overview.obj_parent_uid` to `T_Overview.obj_uid`. NULL values in `obj_parent_uid` are translated to NULL in `intparentid`.

Answer (score 2):

Your update is wrong, there is no relation between T_Overview and (T_Overview + mytable).

This one should work:

```
UPDATE T_Overview SET intid = mytable.rn 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mytable.obj_uid = T_Overview.obj_uid;
```

Offtopic: Your CTE doesn't make much sense, a plain SELECT would give you the same results.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. Yes, that's true. I began making the unnecessary CTE when I ran into trouble. It seems PG makes an implicit cross join, and the update table and the from table are two different entities. That explains why I had trouble with the syntax until I aliased the from table. Very strange... Is this standard-SQL, or is this a PostGre oddity ?